# How to train network on images of different sizes Pytorch

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I  am trying to feed the Neural network  dataset of images and I am getting this error
I don't know what might be the cause as all the images have different sizes
I have also tried to change batch sizes and kernels but I had no success with this.

```
 File "c:\Users\david\Desktop\cs_agent\main.py", line 49, in <module>
    for i, data in enumerate(train_loader, 0):
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 530, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 570, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 52, in fetch
    return self.collate_fn(data)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 172, in default_collate
    return [default_collate(samples) for samples in transposed]  # Backwards compatibility.
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 172, in <listcomp>
    return [default_collate(samples) for samples in transposed]  # Backwards compatibility.
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 138, in default_collate
    return torch.stack(batch, 0, out=out)
RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [3, 300, 535] at entry 0 and [3, 1080, 1920] at entry 23
```

this is my main file

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch
import dataset 
import os 
from torch.utils.data import  DataLoader
import torch.nn as nn

import torchvision
import check_device

import neural_network
import torch.optim as optim

EPS = 1.e-7
LR=0.5
WEIGHT_DECAY=0.5
batch_size =50
#DATA LOADING ###################################################################################################################



test_dataset =dataset.csHeadBody(csv_file="images\\test_labels.csv",root_dir="images\\test")
train_dataset =dataset.csHeadBody(csv_file="images\\train_labels.csv",root_dir="images\\train")
train_loader =DataLoader(dataset =train_dataset,batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True)
test_loader =DataLoader(dataset=test_dataset,batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True)




#DATA LOADING ###################################################################################################################END


#NEURAL NET #####################################################################################################################################################

net=neural_network.Net()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)


#NEURAL NET END ######################################################################################



for epoch in range(2):  # loop over the dataset multiple times

    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, data in enumerate(train_loader, 0):
        # get the inputs; data is a list of [inputs, labels]
        print(data)
        inputs, labels = data

        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # forward + backward + optimize
        outputs = net(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # print statistics
        running_loss += loss.item()
        if i % 2000 == 1999:    # print every 2000 mini-batches
            print(f'[{epoch + 1}, {i + 1:5d}] loss: {running_loss / 2000:.3f}')
            running_loss = 0.0

print('Finished Training')
```

and this is my  dataset file

```
class csHeadBody(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv_file, root_dir, transform=None, target_transform=None):
        self.img_labels = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transform
        self.target_transform = target_transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.img_labels)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_path = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.img_labels.iloc[idx, 0])
        
        image = read_image(img_path)
        label = self.img_labels.iloc[idx, 1]
        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        if self.target_transform:
            label = self.target_transform(label)
        return image, label
```

this is my neural network architecture

```
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.nn as nn
import torch


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 535, 535)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1) # flatten all dimensions except batch
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: The error was due to different input sizes passed to `collate_fn`. If you need to use different input sizes then you must deal with that in transforms (e.g. SmallestMaxSize + Pad or LongestMaxSize + Crop) or write a custom batch sampler.

The error was actually not related to the neural network architecture. It was related to the fact that you tried to create a batch composed of images of different sizes (the error said: `stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [3, 300, 535] at entry 0 and [3, 1080, 1920] at entry 23`). When you use `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` with `batch_size` and `shuffle` specified (other args default) then the default `sampler` and `collate_fn` are used (more [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#data-loading-order-and-sampler)). The default `collate_fn` tries to stack the data that comes from the dataset `__getitem__` method. In your case, the `__getitem__` returned images of different sizes (`[3, 300, 535]` and `[3, 1080, 1920]`) and passed those inputs to `torch.stack`, where the error was thrown.

---

There are 2 common possibilities to deal with multiple input size case:

1. Create a proper transform pipeline, which ensures that inputs of same sizes will be returned. For example:

- [SmallestMaxSize](https://albumentations.ai/docs/api_reference/augmentations/geometric/resize/#albumentations.augmentations.geometric.resize.SmallestMaxSize) followed by Pad - will resize and add extra pixels
- [LongestMaxSize](https://albumentations.ai/docs/api_reference/augmentations/geometric/resize/#albumentations.augmentations.geometric.resize.LongestMaxSize) followed by Crop - will resize and crop the image

2. Use custom batch sampler (passed to `DataLoader`) to ensure that in a single batch only images of same size are loaded.

The second option is a bit harder to implement, but in my opinion it is better since we do not add or remove any information from the image (especially good for generative AI purposes). To implement this option we need to store image sizes information (for each loaded filepath) in the dataset class. Then in custom sampler we will use that information to create batches with indices related to only the images of same size.

1. **`Dataset`** class

```
from typing import Callable
import torchvision.datasets
import imagesize
from PIL import Image

class FilepathsDataset(torchvision.datasets.VisionDataset):
    def __init__(
        self,
        image_filepaths: list[str],
        transform: Callable,
    ):
        self.image_filepaths = image_filepaths

        imgsz_idxs = {}
        for idx, path in enumerate(image_filepaths):
            # imagesize package loads only the file headers so it works really fast
            width, height = imagesize.get(path) 
            size = (width, height)
            if size not in imgsz_idxs:
                imgsz_idxs[size] = [idx]
            else:
                imgsz_idxs[size].append(idx)

        self.imgsz_idxs = imgsz_idxs
        self.transform = transform


    def get_raw_data(self, idx: int) -> Image.Image:
        """Return raw image"""
        image_filepath = self.image_filepaths[idx]
        image = Image.open(image_filepath).convert("RGB")
        return image

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.image_filepaths)

    def __getitem__(self, idx: int) -> tuple[Tensor, Tensor]:
        """Return transformed image and mask"""
        target = <some_target> # TODO: load your target here
        image = self.get_raw_data(idx)
        image = self.transform(image)
        return image, target
```

2. Custom **`Sampler`** class

This sampler shuffles indices and drops last batch by default (to make sure all batches have the same number of samples)

```
import copy
import random
from torch.utils.data import Sampler

class SameResolutionSampler(Sampler):
    def __init__(self, batch_size: int, imgsz_idxs: dict[tuple[int, int], list[int]]):
        self.imgsz_idxs = imgsz_idxs
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __iter__(self) -> list[list[int]]:
        imgsz_idxs = copy.deepcopy(self.imgsz_idxs)

        batches = []
        for size in imgsz_idxs:
            while len(imgsz_idxs[size]) >= self.batch_size:  # drop last
                batch_idxs = []
                for i in range(self.batch_size):
                    idx = imgsz_idxs[size].pop()
                    batch_idxs.append(idx)
                batches.append(batch_idxs)
        random.shuffle(batches)
        return iter(batches)

    def __len__(self):
        batches_per_resolution = [
            len(idxs) // self.batch_size for idxs in self.imgsz_idxs.values()
        ]
        return int(sum(batches_per_resolution))
```

3. Create `DataLoader` instance

```
filepaths = _  # TODO: paths to your images 
transform = _  # TODO: your transforms
batch_size = _  # TODO: your batch_size

ds = FilepathsDataset(filepaths, transform)
sampler = SameResolutionSampler(batch_size, ds.imgsz_idxs)
dataloader = DataLoader(ds, batch_sampler=sampler)
```

NOTE: Also if you use the second option (custom sampler) and you train some convolutional neural network with linear head, you must check if the network works with different input sizes or add [Adaptive Pooling](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d.html) before the linear layers to ensure that the sizes are correct.

Answer (score 3):

You need to adjust the parameters of your convolutional and linear layers. The first argument is the number of input channels (3 for standard RGB images in `conv1`), then the number of output channels and then the convolution kernel size. To clarify, I've used named arguments in the code below. The code works for images of a square input size of `224x224` pixels (standard imagenet size, adjust if needed). If you want image size agnostic code you could use something like global average pooling (mean of each channel in the last conv layer). The net below supports both:

```py
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, use_global_average_pooling: bool = False):
        super().__init__()
        self.use_global_average_pooling = use_global_average_pooling
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2))
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3)
        if use_global_average_pooling:
            self.fc_gap = nn.Linear(64, 10)
        else:
            self.fc_1 = nn.Linear(54 * 54 * 64, 84)  # 54 img side times 64 out channels from conv2
            self.fc_2 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))  # img side: (224 - 2) // 2 = 111
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))  # img side: (111 - 2) // 2 =  54
        if self.use_global_average_pooling:
            # mean for global average pooling (mean over channel dimension)
            x = x.mean(dim=(-1, -2))
            x = F.relu(self.fc_gap(x))
        else:  # use all features
            x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
            x = F.relu(self.fc_1(x))
            x = self.fc_2(x)
        return x
```

Additionally, the `torchvision.io.read_image` function used in your `Dataset` returns an `uint8` tensor with integer values from 0 to 255. You'll want floating point values for your network, so you have to divide the result by `255` to get values in the `[0, 1]` range. Furthermore, neural networks work best with normalized inputs (subtracting the mean and then dividing by the standard error of your training dataset). I've added normalization to the image transforms below. For convenience, it is using the imagenet mean and standard error, which should work fine if your images are similar to imagenet images (otherwise you can calculate them on your own images).

Note that the resizing might distort your images (doesn't keep the original aspect ratio). Often this is no problem, but if it is you might want to pad your images with a constant color (e.g. black) to resize them to the required dimensions (there are also transforms for this in the torchvision library).

```py
IMAGENET_MEAN = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
IMAGENET_STD = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
transforms = torchvision.transforms.Compose([
    torchvision.transforms.Lambda(lambda x: x / 255.),
    torchvision.transforms.Normalize(mean=IMAGENET_MEAN, std=IMAGENET_STD),
    torchvision.transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
])
```

You might also need to adjust the code in your `Dataset` to load images as an RGB image (if they also have an alpha channel). This can be done like this:

```py
image = read_image(img_path, mode=torchvision.io.image.ImageReadMode.RGB)
```

You can then initialise your `Dataset` using:

```py
test_dataset = dataset.csHeadBody(csv_file="images\\test_labels.csv", root_dir="images\\test", transform=transforms)
train_dataset = dataset.csHeadBody(csv_file="images\\train_labels.csv", root_dir="images\\train", transform=transforms)
```

I haven't tested the code, let me know if it doesn't work!

Comment: After adding your code I run into this error `TypeError: pic should be PIL Image or ndarray. Got <class 'torch.Tensor'>` I also tried to remove  `torchvision.transoforms.toTensor()` This cause that `RuntimeError: expected scalar type Byte but found Float`

Comment: On which code/line did the second error occur?

Comment: it is triggered by this  `x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))` both of them

Comment: What does the `read_image` function in your `Dataset` do? Could you maybe post its source code? Or is it from some library?

Comment: it is from this library https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.io.read_image.html @asdf

Comment: So this function returns an image as an `uint8` tensor (meaning values ranging from 0 to 255). Deep learning networks usually work on floating point numbers, so you have to divide the image tensor by `255`. Then you should also normalize the image values, since neural networks work better on normalized data. The `Net` itself also needs some changes… I'll update my answer with the needed changes.